# Access query returning duplicate records

Tags: sql, ms-access, join

I have a query that I'm working with in Access that is supposed to take records specified in another query and alter them.  Unfortunately, if I had multiple records selected before, it creates duplicates in this new query.

For example, if I had 2 records selected, it creates two of the same entry for each.  If I had 3 selected, it creates 3 records for each, with a total of 9 records when I only wanted 3.  If i had only one record initially it works perfectly.

I read that it might be a problem with the join, but I'm not sure how to fix it.

Below is my code, I hope I explained myself well enough :/

```
   SELECT 
      GV_transfer3.[Dept ID], 
      GV_transfer3.[Existing Account], 
      GV_transfer3.Class,     
      GV_transfer3.Fund, 
      GV_transfer3.Program, 
      GV_transfer3.Project, 
      GV_transfer3.ID, 
      GV_transfer3.[project Number], 
      GV_transfer3.[Account Number], 
      GV_transfer3.Code, 
      GV_transfer3.Date, 
      GV_transfer3.Vendor, 
      'transferred from ' & Right([GV_transfer3].[Project Number],Len([GV_transfer3].[Project Number])-8) & ' to ' & Right([New Project Number],Len([New Project Number])-8) & '; ' & [GV_transfer3].[Description] AS Description1, 
      GV_transfer3.[Req By], 
      GV_transfer3.[Approved By], 
      GV_transfer3.[Proj# Number], 
      GV_transfer3.[Transferred out], 
      GV_transfer.Action, 
      -[Amount to transfer] AS Amount, 
      0 AS Reconciled, 
      'done ' & (Date()) & '; ' & [amount to transfer] & ' from ' & Right([GV_transfer3].[Project Number],Len([GV_transfer3].[Project Number])-8) & ' to ' & Right([New Project Number],Len([New Project Number])-8) & '; ' & [GV_transfer3].[Comment] AS Comment1, 
      GV_transfer3.Transfer, 
      GV_transfer3.Match, 
      IIf((Date())<=#6/30/2010#,'FY10',IIf((Date()) Between #7/1/2010# And #6/30/2011#,'FY11',IIf((Date()) Between #7/1/2011# And #6/30/2012#,'FY12','FY13'))) AS [Fiscal Year], 
      GV_transfer3.EquipGroupID, 
      GV_transfer3.EquipNumber, 
      GV_transfer3.Rep_Maint_Purchase, 
      Null AS Budget, GV_transfer.[Rel Project], 
      GV_transfer.MEIF, 
      GV_transfer.Released, 
      GV_transfer3.Proposed, GV_transfer3.Funded, 
      GV_transfer3.Declined, 
      GV_transfer3.Indirect, 
      GV_transfer3.DIC, 
      GV_transfer3.Forecast, 
      GV_transfer3.IntFunded, 
      GV_transfer3.Invoice, 
      GV_transfer3.VContract, 
      GV_transfer3.Category, 
      GV_transfer3.Activity
    FROM GV_transfer3 
    INNER JOIN GV_transfer 
    ON GV_transfer3.ID = GV_transfer.ID;
```

Comment: Please provide some background on why you are joining `GV_transfer` and `GV_transfer3`. What information is missing from `GV_transfer3`

Comment: GV_transfer3 is a table that is behind the form where you would specify the changes you are making.  GV_transfer has the original record.  This query is supposed to bring them together to create a new record with the changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just a guess--but it looks like you have duplicate rows with the same ID in either `GV_transfer` or `GV_transfer3` or both. You will need to ensure that both tables use unique IDs. One way to check is to run the following query on the tables, one by one:

```
select ID, count(ID) as num_times
from GV_transfer
group by ID
```

... and the same query for `GV_transfer3`, with the table name modified.

Comment: They are IDs for a the larger project number that the records are a part of, not for the record themselves.

Comment: Ah, that explains it. To get the same number of rows output as you give input, you must join the tables on fields that uniquely identify each row. You must therefore find or create a _key_ for each of your tables--that is, one column or a combination of columns, that uniquely identifies each row in the table. Then you can join on the key.

Comment: YES!  I didn't know that you could have a multiple columns as a primary key, and that's what I needed to have in order to specify my rows.  So thank you, you probably just saved my job.

Comment: Ah, then I'm glad I answered  if you want to know more, check out _SQL and Relational Theory_ by C.J. Date.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using the DISTINCT command. using SQL in access.
It will eliminate duplication in a column/columns.
Make a new query and select the current query you made that gave you the duplication.

SELECT DISTINCT("name of column")
FROM "name of table/query";

That will make a new query eliminating all duplication.
Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I'd try using a LEFT JOIN instead of an INNER JOIN.